# Best way to handle long strings in python

Tags: python, string, apache-tika

I am doing some text document processing so that reading a large document file into a string using `apache-tika`.Example:

```
    content = data_manipulate.read_by_tika(document_url)
```

Some cases I need to use content.lower() and some other cases `content`. Since it is a large string what is the best practise to use this string effectively for maximum code optimization?
Is it correct to use two string `content` and `content_lower=content.lower()` and use between them wherever needed?

Comment: What are your _other_ options? When you say "best," you compare A to B. Is there a B?

Comment: A is 'content' and B is 'content_lower'@DYZ

Comment: Nope. A is "use two strings `content` and `content_lower=content.lower()`. Is there any feasible alternative to this? Unless you have a choice, you cannot choose the best.

Comment: My concern is about is it good practise to use like A because content and content_lower consume significantly large memory right?@DYZ

Comment: I understand. But is there an alternative? If there is no alternative, the only solution that you have if the best.

Comment: Another option is declare and assign only one variable content and use between content and content.lower() instead of defining a second variable content_lower?@DYZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142240/discussion-between-akhil-viswam-and-dyz).

Comment: You will still have to generate a copy of `content` every time you need to use the lowercase version. It does not solve the space problem, but hurts the performance.